# Service Fabric 2.1.150 causes MSBuild warning without AutoGenerateBindingRedirects

Tags: msbuild, azure-service-fabric

I just updated to the Azure Service Fabric 2.1.150 SDK and noticed I started getting build warnings when compiling my Manifest (`.sfproj`) projects:

```
C:\Program File (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): 
warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent 
assembly. 
Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. 
For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?inkId=294190.
```

I can following the instructions easily enough and prevent the warnings from appearing by editing the `.sfproj`:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
   <ProjectGuid>12dbad9d-346c-xxxx-xxxx-04ab65fb4cac</ProjectGuid>
   <ProjectVersion>1.1</ProjectVersion>
   <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Question:**  Why did this start happening in 2.1.150 and is it anything I should be worried about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning is showing up in this scenario due to a change in logic in some of the MSBuild files used by the .sfproj in this new version.  Once the next release comes out, it should fix this issue so the warning won't show up anymore.  Your mitigation is fine, nothing to worry about regarding the warning.